# Adobe Connect API list of meetings is not correct

Tags: adobe-connect

I have an adobe connect account in which I am able to create a number of meetings. I am trying to use the API (as detailed [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/8.0/webservices/index.html)) to show a list of available meetings in my application.

I am doing some basic web request calls to the API and parsing the resulting XML data. This part I can do fine.

However, I have now realised that when I add a new meeting it does not appear in the API call immediately. Probably took about 30 minutes to appear.

My web request query for getting the list of meeting is like...

```
https://[API-URL]/api/xml?action=report-bulk-objects&filter-type=meeting
```

I have also tried doing this as a POST request, and adding a random param to ensure it is not a caching issue - no such luck

Is this an issue with the API? Is there a time delay on API data updates? Am I missing something from the query string? or maybe there is a default filter in place that I need to explicit remove within the query?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where does one find the [API-URL], I can't seem to find documentation on it.

Comment: @dieheld: It's just a placeholder to mean that [THE URL FOR YOUR API GOES HERE] If you have an adobe connect account and have even tried to understand how to use it then you should be able to work that out

Comment: my bad, I only released afterwards the you need to have the API installed on your own server or at least one they setup for you, I thought that Adobe would host the api and that there would be some sort of fixed url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk API you are using is an aggregate and may take some time for a backend process to run in order to update the meeting list.  You don't specify your use-case, but if you are simply looking for your own meetings, then you should use the report-my-meetings call instead, which is real-time.

good luck!

Comment: The idea is that it will show all meetings that a user is able to join. So not just the users meetings but all available meetings. The user viewing is not actually going to be registered on adobe connect at that time. We will create a user account for them should they choose to register for a meeting. So I need to see all meetings for an account (not just one user). Does this mean I am back to using report-bulk?

Answer (score 1):

My use case is similar to that of musefan—I need to be able to list all meetings regardless of who creates them, as well as those cases when a user is not logged into the site.  I had a notion for how to do this and have tested it to make sure it works.  Here goes:

1. Create a special user (e.g., global_user@mydomain.com) and set them
   up as an Administrator in your Adobe Connect account.
2. Log in with this user for all your background API calls.  (I'm using a modified version of PHP code I found here: https://github.com/sc0rp10/AdobeConnect-php-api-client. It uses PHP curl for the calls.)
3. When a new meeting is created, set view permissions for your user for that meeting via the 'permissions-update' API
   call:

   {your domain}/api/xml?action=permissions-update&acl-id=123456789&principal-id=987654321&permission-id=view

Now when you call 'report-my-meetings', you will see every meeting for which your user is a listed as participant—which, if you follow the above, should be all of them.

Cheers!